Centering Crosses on Horizontal Line with Tailwind CSS
I'm trying to create a design where a horizontal line spans the width of a container, and there are two cross icons (SVGs) aligned perfectly at both ends of the line. The crosses need to be centered vertically on the line, and the line should not extend beyond the edges of the container. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

A horizontal line that spans exactly the width of its container.
Crosses (+) perfectly centered vertically on the line.
No extra lines extending on the left or right beyond the crosses.

I've tried multiple approaches, but the layout still doesn't align correctly. Sometimes the line is too short, sometimes too long, and occasionally the crosses aren't centered properly. Here’s my current code:
Hero.jsx
import "./text.css";
import stars from "./stars.json";
import { SparklesIcon } from "lucide-react";
import Lottie from "lottie-react";
import Section from "./Section";
import { BottomLine } from "./design/Hero";

function Hero() {
  return (
    <Section
      className="pt-[12rem] -mt-[5.25rem]"
      crosses={true}
      crossesOffset="lg:translate-y-[5.25rem]"
      customPaddings
      id="hero"
    >
      <div className="relative container max-w-4xl text-center mx-auto mt-20">
        <div className="mx-auto inline-flex items-center justify-center font-inter text-white border-[#1e1e1e] bg-[#1e1e1e]/40 border px-4 py-2 rounded-xl">
          <SparklesIcon
            fill="#1e1e1e"
            className="w-5 h-5 text-[#dee34e] mr-2"
          />
          Our New AI Feature Has Just Returned
        </div>

        <h1 className="mt-5 text-5xl lg:text-[80px] font-semibold text-white font-inter">
          <span className="bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 via-purple-500 to-pink-500 text-transparent bg-clip-text">
            Supercharge
          </span>
          <br /> your journey
        </h1>

        <p className="mt-5 mb-8 text-lg text-[#ebebeb] font-inter max-w-sm mx-auto">
          Walk, run, transport better with knowledge of areas with a high and
          low concentration.
        </p>

        <a
          className="px-6 py-3 text-xl font-semibold text-black bg-white rounded-xl font-inter hover:opacity-90 transition-opacity"
          href="#"
        >
          Use BMap for Free
        </a>

        <div
          className="absolute inset-0 flex justify-center items-center pointer-events-none"
          aria-hidden="true"
        >
          <div className="relative w-[500px] h-[500px] rounded-full bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 via-pink-500 to-blue-500 opacity-60 blur-3xl animate-pulse"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      

      <BottomLine />
    </Section>
  );
}

export default Hero;

Section.jsx
import SectionSvg from "../assets/svg/SectionSvg";

const Section = ({
  className,
  id,
  crosses,
  crossesOffset,
  customPaddings,
  children,
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      id={id}
      className={`
      relative max-w-6xl mx-auto 
      ${
        customPaddings ||
        `py-10 lg:py-16 xl:py-20 ${crosses ? "lg:py-32 xl:py-40" : ""}`
      } 
      ${className || ""}`}
    >
      {children}

      <div className="hidden absolute top-0 left-5 w-0.25 h-full bg-stroke-1 pointer-events-none md:block lg:left-7.5 xl:left-10" />
      <div className="hidden absolute top-0 right-5 w-0.25 h-full bg-stroke-1 pointer-events-none md:block lg:right-7.5 xl:right-10" />

      {crosses && (
        <>
          <div
            className={`hidden absolute top-0 left-7.5 right-7.5 h-0.25 bg-stroke-1 ${
              crossesOffset && crossesOffset
            } pointer-events-none lg:block xl:left-10 right-10`}
          />
          <SectionSvg crossesOffset={crossesOffset} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Section;

The code with the bottom line:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { MouseParallax } from "react-just-parallax";

import PlusSvg from "../../assets/svg/PlusSvg";

export const Gradient = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="relative z-1 h-6 mx-2.5 bg-n-11 shadow-xl rounded-b-[1.25rem] lg:h-6 lg:mx-8" />
      <div className="relative z-1 h-6 mx-6 bg-n-11/70 shadow-xl rounded-b-[1.25rem] lg:h-6 lg:mx-20" />
    </>
  );
};

export const BottomLine = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="hidden absolute top-[55.25rem] left-10 right-10 h-0.25 bg-n-6 pointer-events-none xl:block" />

      <PlusSvg className="hidden absolute top-[54.9375rem] left-[2.1875rem] z-2 pointer-events-none xl:block" />

      <PlusSvg className="hidden absolute top-[54.9375rem] right-[2.1875rem] z-2 pointer-events-none xl:block" />
    </>
  );
};

const Rings = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 w-[65.875rem] aspect-square border border-n-2/10 rounded-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" />
      <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 w-[51.375rem] aspect-square border border-n-2/10 rounded-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" />
      <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 w-[36.125rem] aspect-square border border-n-2/10 rounded-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" />
      <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 w-[23.125rem] aspect-square border border-n-2/10 rounded-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2" />
    </>
  );
};

export const BackgroundCircles = ({ parallaxRef }) => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="absolute -top-[42.375rem] left-1/2 w-[78rem] aspect-square border border-n-2/5 rounded-full -translate-x-1/2 md:-top-[38.5rem] xl:-top-[32rem]">
      <Rings />

      {/* Moving background colored circle balls */}
      <MouseParallax strength={0.07} parallaxContainerRef={parallaxRef}>
        <div className="absolute bottom-1/2 left-1/2 w-0.25 h-1/2 origin-bottom rotate-[46deg]">
          <div
            className={`w-2 h-2 -ml-1 -mt-36 bg-gradient-to-b from-[#DD734F] to-[#1A1A32] rounded-full transition-transform duration-500 ease-out ${
              mounted ? "translate-y-0 opacity-100" : "translate-y-10 opacity-0"
            }`}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="absolute bottom-1/2 left-1/2 w-0.25 h-1/2 origin-bottom -rotate-[56deg]">
          <div
            className={`w-4 h-4 -ml-1 -mt-32 bg-gradient-to-b from-[#DD734F] to-[#1A1A32] rounded-full transition-transform duration-500 ease-out ${
              mounted ? "translate-y-0 opacity-100" : "translate-y-10 opacity-0"
            }`}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="absolute bottom-1/2 left-1/2 w-0.25 h-1/2 origin-bottom rotate-[54deg]">
          <div
            className={`hidden w-4 h-4 -ml-1 mt-[12.9rem] bg-gradient-to-b from-[#B9AEDF] to-[#1A1A32] rounded-full xl:block transit transition-transform duration-500 ease-out ${
              mounted ? "translate-y-0 opacity-100" : "translate-y-10 opacity-0"
            }`}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="absolute bottom-1/2 left-1/2 w-0.25 h-1/2 origin-bottom -rotate-[65deg]">
          <div
            className={`w-3 h-3 -ml-1.5 mt-52 bg-gradient-to-b from-[#B9AEDF] to-[#1A1A32] rounded-full transition-transform duration-500 ease-out ${
              mounted ? "translate-y-0 opacity-100" : "translate-y-10 opacity-0"
            }`}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="absolute bottom-1/2 left-1/2 w-0.25 h-1/2 origin-bottom -rotate-[85deg]">
          <div
            className={`w-6 h-6 -ml-3 -mt-3 bg-gradient-to-b from-[#88E5BE] to-[#1A1A32] rounded-full transition-transform duration-500 ease-out ${
              mounted ? "translate-y-0 opacity-100" : "translate-y-10 opacity-0"
            }`}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="absolute bottom-1/2 left-1/2 w-0.25 h-1/2 origin-bottom rotate-[70deg]">
          <div
            className={`w-6 h-6 -ml-3 -mt-3 bg-gradient-to-b from-[#88E5BE] to-[#1A1A32] rounded-full transition-transform duration-500 ease-out ${
              mounted ? "translate-y-0 opacity-100" : "translate-y-10 opacity-0"
            }`}
          />
        </div>
      </MouseParallax>
    </div>
  );
};

PlusSvg
const PlusSvg = ({ className = "" }) => {
    return (
      <svg className={`${className} || ""`} width="11" height="11" fill="none">
        <path
          d="M7 1a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h1a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V8a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H8a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V1z"
          fill="#ada8c4"
        />
      </svg>
    );
  };
  
  export default PlusSvg;

SectionSvg
import PlusSvg from "./PlusSvg";

const SectionSvg = ({ crossesOffset }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <PlusSvg
        className={`hidden absolute -top-[0.3125rem] left-[1.5625rem] ${
          crossesOffset && crossesOffset
        } pointer-events-none lg:block xl:left-[2.1875rem]`}
      />

      <PlusSvg
        className={`hidden absolute  -top-[0.3125rem] right-[1.5625rem] ${
          crossesOffset && crossesOffset
        } pointer-events-none lg:block xl:right-[2.1875rem]`}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default SectionSvg;

I have attatched all my main code here, here is an image of what i am seeing.
https://ibb.co/MZW5sLP
Thank you!
